# How to get referred user details from referral URL?

Tags: java, android, url, referrals

In my app i have to send app install link to others ,after successful sending when that user install that app need to get referred user information in app when user use that app

If one user suggest app to another user by URL when he try to register ,in that time we need to get referred user id without asking that user, i have searched alot but didn't get any information about this.

If anyone have suggestion please post it.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/).

Comment: Hi @Thomas Meinhart thanks for the replay, can we get information from url i want to get the referred user id which is maintained in our database .SO when other user register so i can link with that user is it possible.

Comment: Hi @Akhil. We pass information as url parameter like &invited_by=id.

Comment: How to get that id when user install that app. I have one more doubt about new thing after successful instal we will get the referred id after saving the id in shared pref what is user clear data from settings we will loss id how to handle it.

Comment: can you explain littlebit of Firbase Invites i never used that one.

Comment: Firebase Invite is more or less a Firebase Dynamic Link. You can create a dynamic link and send it to other people. If somebody clicks on that link he will be lead to the playstore and can install your app or if the app is already installed the app will open and the link is passed in the app. please read the docs for more information. https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

Comment: Thanks for replay i will try Invites.